# Convert st_astext result to single text columns

Tags: coordinates, postgis, point

I need some help with postgis.

I have made a point geometry that have converted to text through st_astext.

I currently have these three columns:

```
object_id(uuid)                         komnr(int)   st_astext_result(text)
2bcc1b26-0a7c-472a-9e74-9cadfefc2d44    320          POINT(687989.85 6135746.91)
```

I would like two columns each containing the east and north coordinate in the same syntax as it is now. Do you have any suggestions to how i may do this?

Preferred outcome would be:

```
east         north
687989.85    6135746.91
```

Comment: Would st_x, and st_y help me solve my problem? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42970/how-to-get-coordinates-from-geometry-in-postgis

Comment: It would. SELECT ST_Y(geom) as north, ST_X(geom) as east FROM table_name